# Saving State Parameter back to Class

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I am trying to create two views that display a list of categories that are **in use** or **not in use**. The following code displays only the not in use categories.

I would like to be able to tap a category and have it disappear from the **not in use** view and appear in the **in use** view and vice versa. My view is working with the list and button, but I am having trouble saving the state parameter back to my class structure. I am seeing the error "Cannot assign to property: 'item' is a 'let' constant" in the function saveStatus().

I was using **ForEach(0..<self.categories.catItem.count, id: .self) { index in** to display the categories but there were gaps in the list because some categories were assigned to the In Use view instead of the Not In Use view. So now filtering is displaying the list more smoothly. But the problem I am having is how to save the change in status of catShow (the Bool I use to distinguish between views). I was using the index form of ForEach() to help do this.

Thanks for your insight.

```
struct CatModel:  Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var catName: String
    var catPix: String
    var catShow: Bool        // false = not in use; true = in use
}


class Categories: ObservableObject {

     @Published var filteredInUse: [CatModel] = []
     @Published var filteredNotInUse: [CatModel] = []
     @Published var catItem: [CatModel] {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(catItem) {      // save categories
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "workCat")
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.catItem = []

        // catShow: 1 = category available for use; 2 = category currently being used
        let item0 = CatModel(catName: "Category 1", catPix: "bed.double.fill", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item0)

        let item1 = CatModel(catName: "Category 2", catPix: "cart", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item1)

        let item2 = CatModel(catName: "Category 3", catPix: "airplane", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item2)

        let item3 = CatModel(catName: "Category 4", catPix: "tram", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item3)

        let item4 = CatModel(catName: "Category 5", catPix: "bus.fill", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item4)

        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(catItem) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "workCat")
        }
        self.updateStatus()
    }

    func updateStatus() {
        filteredInUse = catItem.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.catShow == true
        })

        filteredNotInUse = catItem.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.catShow == false
        })
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var categories = Categories()

    @State private var showStatus: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack ( spacing: 6) {

            Text("Not In Use Categories")

            ForEach(categories.filteredNotInUse, id: \.id) { item in

                Button(action: {

                    showStatus = true

                }){

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: item.catPix)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 18, height: 18)

                    Text(item.catName)
                        .padding(.leading, 40)
                    }
                }
            //    categories.catItem[index].catShow = showStatus
             //   item.catShow = showStatus
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `struct` for the `CatModel`: structs are immutable, so you can't mutate a variable inside of it.

The first recommendation is to create CatModel in Core Data: if you do that, your code will work. It will also work if `CatModel` is a `class`.

If you don't want to/ can't use Core Data or a class, the solution can be to completely replace a `CatModel` that holds `catShow = false` with another instance where `catShow = true`.

First, create a property in `CatModel` to provide a new instance, changing the `catShow` value:

```
struct CatModel:  Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var catName: String
    var catPix: String
    var catShow: Bool        // false = not in use; true = in use
    
    /// Provides a new instance, toggling `catShow`.
    var toggleCatShow: CatModel {

        // Note: by creating a new instance, the new id will be different
        CatModel(catName: catName, catPix: catPix, catShow: !catShow)
    }
}
```

Second, create a function in the `Categories` view model that will replace the existing instance with a new one, in the same position:

```
class Categories: ObservableObject {

     @Published var filteredInUse: [CatModel] = []
     @Published var filteredNotInUse: [CatModel] = []
     @Published var catItem: [CatModel] {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(catItem) {      // save categories
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "workCat")
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.catItem = []

        // catShow: 1 = category available for use; 2 = category currently being used
        let item0 = CatModel(catName: "Category 1", catPix: "bed.double.fill", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item0)

        let item1 = CatModel(catName: "Category 2", catPix: "cart", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item1)

        let item2 = CatModel(catName: "Category 3", catPix: "airplane", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item2)

        let item3 = CatModel(catName: "Category 4", catPix: "tram", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item3)

        let item4 = CatModel(catName: "Category 5", catPix: "bus.fill", catShow: false)
        self.catItem.append(item4)

        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(catItem) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "workCat")
        }
        self.updateStatus()
    }

    func updateStatus() {
        filteredInUse = catItem.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.catShow == true
        })

        filteredNotInUse = catItem.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.catShow == false
        })
    }
    
    /// Replaces an instance of `CatModel` by changing its `catShow` value.
    func setCatShow(forId id: UUID) {
        let index = catItem.firstIndex { $0.id == id }
        if let index = index {
            catItem.replaceSubrange(index...index, with: [catItem[index].toggleCatShow])
        }
        
        // Refresh the filtered arrays
        updateStatus()
    }
}
```

Finally, call the method inside the `Button()`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var categories = Categories()

    @State private var showStatus: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack ( spacing: 6) {

            Text("Not In Use Categories")

            ForEach(categories.filteredNotInUse, id: \.id) { item in

                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        showStatus = true
                        
                        // Call the method on the view model
                        categories.setCatShow(forId: item.id)
                    }

                }){

                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: item.catPix)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 18, height: 18)

                    Text("\(item.catName), in use: \(String(describing: item.catShow))")
                        .padding(.leading, 40)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before tapping category 3:
[image]

After tapping category 3:
[image]

Replacing:

```
ForEach(categories.filteredNotInUse, id: \.id) { item in
```

with:

```
ForEach(categories.catItem, id: \.id) { item in
```

Let's you see **ALL** the lines and their `catShow` values. In such case:

Before tapping category 3:
[image]

After tapping category 3:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Hunter Lion: All this has been working fine until I decided to reorganize how the categories are used. I am already using coreData for app entries.  I don't expect to support more than 20 categories. So you are saying my best option is to convert the CatMotel to a class? I am getting all kinds of errors in the Categories class for item0 - item4 when I do that. How do I resolve the errors?

Comment: Ok I made your changes above. Did you intend for func SetCatShow() to be outside init()? I am not getting errors, but tapping categories in view doesn't make them disappear.

Comment: @GalenSmith: the new func **must** be outside “init()”. Put it at the bottom of the class, like in the sample code I posted. I tested it with iOS 15.

Comment: I have to admit I don’t fully understand what you are doing with this new logic. When  I run my code, my list in the view doesn’t change. When I run the debugger, and let it break after toggleCatShow in the struct CatModel, the value of catShow is false while when looking at toggleCatShow in the console I see another catShow with the value of true. So it looks like in the method updateStatus() where the filtered list is created that I’m looking at the wrong catShow. Is that true? How do I access the new catShow?

Comment: @GalenSmith: sorry, I guess I can't help you in this case. I have now posted the *whole* code: it works perfectly in Xcode 15.4, iPhone 13. The `catShow` does **not** update because, as you can see in the answer, it's a `struct`, it's immutable. Instead, the code replaces the instance of `CatModel` in the list `catItem` with a new instance, but with an inverted `catShow` (true instead of false). Other than that, I still recommend using Core Data or a class for `Cat Model`.

Comment: Thanks @HunterLion, I was missing the 2nd call to UpdateStatus()